# How To merge first three column of last table row in latex?

Tags: latex, row

How can I merge last column in latex? I am trying to remove the horizontal border line from the last row so It look like its merged!

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
        \textbf{Component} & \textbf{Cost/Unit} & \textbf{Total Quatity Used} & \textbf{Total Price} \\ \hline
        1 Gbps Switch & 4850 & 6 & 29100 \\ \hline
        100 Mbps Switch & 2535 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
        M12 100 MHz Copper Cable & 35 & 84 & 2940 \\ \hline
        Total Price & ~ & ~ & 32040 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I also want to bring all the words in the Middle of cell not starting from the left.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to switch from normal tables to the `tabularray` package. This package makes it really easy to merge cells:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={llll},
      row{1}={font=\bfseries},
      hlines,
      vlines
    }
        Component & Cost/Unit & Total Quatity Used & Total Price \\ 
        1 Gbps Switch & 4850 & 6 & 29100 \\ 
        100 Mbps Switch & 2535 & 0 & 0 \\ 
        M12 100 MHz Copper Cable & 35 & 84 & 2940 \\ 
        \SetCell[c=3]{halign=c} Total Price & ~ & ~ & 32040 \\ 
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! how can I bring the total proce in the middle of the cell?

Comment: @SanchitJain The only word I understand in your sentence is "using" - so I'm probably not the best person to ask about these questions :)

Comment: Hi could you please help me with my question .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74866905/table-not-fitting-into-one-page