# Table not fitting into one page

Tags: latex, tabular

Not able to fit table into one page. I want this table to extended into next page. How can I do that?
My code looks like this I have around 50 rows. Please someone help me fitting this table in 2 pages.

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
        Sender & Receiver & Total(Bits) &  Frame Rate (ms)  \\ \hline
        VCU & ACU & 88 &  10  \\ \hline
        VCU & BCU & 488 &  10  \\ \hline
        VCU & DataRecorder & 536 &  10  \\ \hline
        VCU & DDC & 120 &  20  \\ \hline
        VCU & HMI & 424 &  30  \\ \hline
        VCU & OBU & 146800 &  50  \\ \hline
        VCU & Ticket & 200 &  50  \\ \hline
        VCU & BMS & 50 &  50  \\ \hline
        VCU & FuelCell & 50 &  50  \\ \hline
        VCU & HVAC & 152 &  100  \\ \hline
        VCU & ILCU & 152 &  100  \\ \hline
        VCU & ELCU & 152 &  100  \\ \hline
        VCU & DCU & 56 &  100  \\ \hline
        VCU & TCU & 464 &  200  \\ \hline
        ACU & VCU & 1000 &  10  \\ \hline
        Amplifier & OBU & 8 &  20  \\ \hline
        ATP & OBU & 64 &  20  \\ \hline
        ATP & VCU & 104 &  20  \\ \hline
        BCU & VCU & 856 &  20  \\ \hline
        Camera & CCTVDisp & 146800 &  30  \\ \hline
        Camera & CCTVRecorder & 146800 &  30  \\ \hline
        Camera & VCU & 32 &  30  \\ \hline
        Camera & HMI & 32 &  30  \\ \hline
        DataRecorder & VCU & 768 &  20  \\ \hline
        DCU & HMI & 344 &  20  \\ \hline
        DCU & VCU & 352 &  20  \\ \hline
        DDC & ATP & 64 &  20  \\ \hline
        DDC & BCU & 16 &  20  \\ \hline
        DDC & VCU & 136 &  100  \\ \hline
        HMI & DCU & 32 &  20  \\ \hline
        HMI & OBU & 26656 &  20  \\ \hline
        HMI & VCU & 240 &  20  \\ \hline
        HVAC & VCU & 432 &  20  \\ \hline
        ELCU & HMI & 112 &  20  \\ \hline
        ELCU & VCU & 120 &  30  \\ \hline
        ILCU & HMI & 16 &  10  \\ \hline
        ILCU & VCU & 48 &  10  \\ \hline
        MC & VCU & 184 &  10  \\ \hline
        CCTVRecorder & HMI & 96 &  50  \\ \hline
        CCTVRecorder & VCU & 96 &  200  \\ \hline
        OBU & ExtDisp & 146800 &  30  \\ \hline
        OBU & IntDisp & 146800 &  30  \\ \hline
        OBU & Amplifier & 26672 &  30  \\ \hline
        OBU & HMI & 13328 &  30  \\ \hline
        OBU & PEC & 13344 &  30  \\ \hline
        OBU & VCU & 64 &  30  \\ \hline
        PEC & OBU & 13416 &  50  \\ \hline
        PEC & VCU & 8 &  50  \\ \hline
        TCU & VCU & 2904 &  50  \\ \hline
        Ticket & VCU & 200 &  50  \\ \hline
        PassangerCount & VCU & 100 &  50  \\ \hline
        FuelCell & VCU & 448 &  50  \\ \hline
        BMS & VCU & 448 &  50 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I tries using longtblr but did not help

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Always make a compilable example including a class  and the necessary packages.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the feedback ill take care of that next time.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to change the requirements after you got an answer. That's very bad style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with another package, [`longtable`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable), updated in 2021.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \caption[Short caption]{Long caption if needed}\label{lt}\\
    \hline
        Sender & Receiver & Total(Bits) &  Frame Rate (ms)  \\ \hline
        \endfirsthead
    \hline
        Sender & Receiver & Total(Bits) &  Frame Rate (ms)  \\ %\hline
        \endhead
    %\hline
        \endfoot
    %\hline
        \endlastfoot
        VCU & ACU & 88 &  10  \\ \hline
        VCU & BCU & 488 &  10  \\ \hline
        VCU & DataRecorder & 536 &  10  \\ \hline
        VCU & DDC & 120 &  20  \\ \hline
        VCU & HMI & 424 &  30  \\ \hline
        VCU & OBU & 146800 &  50  \\ \hline
        VCU & Ticket & 200 &  50  \\ \hline
        VCU & BMS & 50 &  50  \\ \hline
        VCU & FuelCell & 50 &  50  \\ \hline
        VCU & HVAC & 152 &  100  \\ \hline
        VCU & ILCU & 152 &  100  \\ \hline
        VCU & ELCU & 152 &  100  \\ \hline
        VCU & DCU & 56 &  100  \\ \hline
        VCU & TCU & 464 &  200  \\ \hline
        ACU & VCU & 1000 &  10  \\ \hline
        Amplifier & OBU & 8 &  20  \\ \hline
        ATP & OBU & 64 &  20  \\ \hline
        ATP & VCU & 104 &  20  \\ \hline
        BCU & VCU & 856 &  20  \\ \hline
        Camera & CCTVDisp & 146800 &  30  \\ \hline
        Camera & CCTVRecorder & 146800 &  30  \\ \hline
        Camera & VCU & 32 &  30  \\ \hline
        Camera & HMI & 32 &  30  \\ \hline
        DataRecorder & VCU & 768 &  20  \\ \hline
        DCU & HMI & 344 &  20  \\ \hline
        DCU & VCU & 352 &  20  \\ \hline
        DDC & ATP & 64 &  20  \\ \hline
        DDC & BCU & 16 &  20  \\ \hline
        DDC & VCU & 136 &  100  \\ \hline
        HMI & DCU & 32 &  20  \\ \hline
        HMI & OBU & 26656 &  20  \\ \hline
        HMI & VCU & 240 &  20  \\ \hline
        HVAC & VCU & 432 &  20  \\ \hline
        ELCU & HMI & 112 &  20  \\ \hline
        ELCU & VCU & 120 &  30  \\ \hline
        ILCU & HMI & 16 &  10  \\ \hline
        ILCU & VCU & 48 &  10  \\ \hline
        MC & VCU & 184 &  10  \\ \hline
        CCTVRecorder & HMI & 96 &  50  \\ \hline
        CCTVRecorder & VCU & 96 &  200  \\ \hline
        OBU & ExtDisp & 146800 &  30  \\ \hline
        OBU & IntDisp & 146800 &  30  \\ \hline
        OBU & Amplifier & 26672 &  30  \\ \hline
        OBU & HMI & 13328 &  30  \\ \hline
        OBU & PEC & 13344 &  30  \\ \hline
        OBU & VCU & 64 &  30  \\ \hline
        PEC & OBU & 13416 &  50  \\ \hline
        PEC & VCU & 8 &  50  \\ \hline
        TCU & VCU & 2904 &  50  \\ \hline
        Ticket & VCU & 200 &  50  \\ \hline
        PassangerCount & VCU & 100 &  50  \\ \hline
        FuelCell & VCU & 448 &  50  \\ \hline
        BMS & VCU & 448 &  50 \\ \hline 
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The output looks threshold but it can be refined:

[image: screenshot of output]

Still, this table is not a float.

Answer (score 3):

The `table` environment does not allow page breaks. If you want your `longtblr` to break across packages, don't put it in a floating environment like `table`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{longtblr}[
      caption={text}
    ]{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
        Sender & Receiver & Total(Bits) &  Frame Rate (ms)  \\ \hline
        VCU & ACU & 88 &  10  \\ \hline
        VCU & BCU & 488 &  10  \\ \hline
        VCU & DataRecorder & 536 &  10  \\ \hline
        VCU & DDC & 120 &  20  \\ \hline
        VCU & HMI & 424 &  30  \\ \hline
        VCU & OBU & 146800 &  50  \\ \hline
        VCU & Ticket & 200 &  50  \\ \hline
        VCU & BMS & 50 &  50  \\ \hline
        VCU & FuelCell & 50 &  50  \\ \hline
        VCU & HVAC & 152 &  100  \\ \hline
        VCU & ILCU & 152 &  100  \\ \hline
        VCU & ELCU & 152 &  100  \\ \hline
        VCU & DCU & 56 &  100  \\ \hline
        VCU & TCU & 464 &  200  \\ \hline
        ACU & VCU & 1000 &  10  \\ \hline
        Amplifier & OBU & 8 &  20  \\ \hline
        ATP & OBU & 64 &  20  \\ \hline
        ATP & VCU & 104 &  20  \\ \hline
        BCU & VCU & 856 &  20  \\ \hline
        Camera & CCTVDisp & 146800 &  30  \\ \hline
        Camera & CCTVRecorder & 146800 &  30  \\ \hline
        Camera & VCU & 32 &  30  \\ \hline
        Camera & HMI & 32 &  30  \\ \hline
        DataRecorder & VCU & 768 &  20  \\ \hline
        DCU & HMI & 344 &  20  \\ \hline
        DCU & VCU & 352 &  20  \\ \hline
        DDC & ATP & 64 &  20  \\ \hline
        DDC & BCU & 16 &  20  \\ \hline
        DDC & VCU & 136 &  100  \\ \hline
        HMI & DCU & 32 &  20  \\ \hline
        HMI & OBU & 26656 &  20  \\ \hline
        HMI & VCU & 240 &  20  \\ \hline
        HVAC & VCU & 432 &  20  \\ \hline
        ELCU & HMI & 112 &  20  \\ \hline
        ELCU & VCU & 120 &  30  \\ \hline
        ILCU & HMI & 16 &  10  \\ \hline
        ILCU & VCU & 48 &  10  \\ \hline
        MC & VCU & 184 &  10  \\ \hline
        CCTVRecorder & HMI & 96 &  50  \\ \hline
        CCTVRecorder & VCU & 96 &  200  \\ \hline
        OBU & ExtDisp & 146800 &  30  \\ \hline
        OBU & IntDisp & 146800 &  30  \\ \hline
        OBU & Amplifier & 26672 &  30  \\ \hline
        OBU & HMI & 13328 &  30  \\ \hline
        OBU & PEC & 13344 &  30  \\ \hline
        OBU & VCU & 64 &  30  \\ \hline
        PEC & OBU & 13416 &  50  \\ \hline
        PEC & VCU & 8 &  50  \\ \hline
        TCU & VCU & 2904 &  50  \\ \hline
        Ticket & VCU & 200 &  50  \\ \hline
        PassangerCount & VCU & 100 &  50  \\ \hline
        FuelCell & VCU & 448 &  50  \\ \hline
        BMS & VCU & 448 &  50 \\ \hline
    \end{longtblr}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Thanksfor the answer it helped, but can you tell me how can I add captions in it also because I can't add caption now.

Comment: Thanks alot it worked. But I got problem with border. The table which is starting on the next page does not have horizontal border on the top.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hczHK.png border works just fine. Please ask a new question if you have a problem with the border.

Comment: Yeah I solved the problem of the border.